# How to set a plot title after plot window is closed in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to change the plot title based on the user selection after the plot window is closed.

```
    ax = pd.rolling_mean(dataToPlot_plot[startTime:endTime][['plotValue']],mar).plot(linestyle='-', linewidth=3,  markersize=9, color='#FECB00')
    ax.legend().set_visible(False)
    titObj = plt.title('Data Plot - '+"\n", fontsize=13)#plot title
    plt.show()#showing the plot

    fig = ax.get_figure()
    fig.set_size_inches(12, 6)
    fig.savefig(savePlot)
```

Now I need change the plot title dynamically based on the user selection on the plot and save it...

```
    ax = pd.rolling_mean(dataToPlot_plot[startTime:endTime][['plotValue']],mar).plot(linestyle='-', linewidth=3,  markersize=9, color='#FECB00')
    ax.legend().set_visible(False)
    titObj = plt.title('Data Plot - '+"\n", fontsize=13)#plot title
    plt.show()#showing the plot

    curVal = ax.get_xlim()
    stdate = int(curVal[0])
    endate = int(curVal[1])
    difdate = endate - stdate 

    fig = ax.get_figure()
    if stdate > 0 and endate > 0:
        if difdate > 365:
            newplotTitle = 'Data Plot - Since from start'
        elif difdate > 28 and difdate < 365:
            newplotTitle = 'Data Plot - Past Month'
        elif difdate < 28:
            newplotTitle = 'Data Plot - Past Days'

        plt.title(newplotTitle+"\n", fontsize=13)#plot title

    fig.set_size_inches(12, 6)
    fig.savefig(savePlot)
```

The new changes is not amending with the old title, Is there any other way to fix this...
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is that the `plt` interface always refers to the "current" figure/axes/etc.

After you've closed the figure, the "current" axes is a new, blank plot.

For this and several other reasons, it's best to stick to the axes methods (except for a handful of functions like `plt.figure`, `plt.subplots`, `plt.show`, etc that make dealing with creating and displaying figures easier).

Using the methods of the axes or figure objects make the relationship to which axes/figure is being modified much more clear.  Otherwise, you need to be aware of what the "current" axes is.

---

In your case, rather than doing `plt.title('blah')`, use `ax.set(title='blah')` (or `ax.set_title`) instead.

Comment: Thanks @Joe Kington, great help... It worked and also have tried with "fig.suptitle(newplotTitle+"\n", fontsize=13)#plot title" is working. Thanks for your time and help